# ANTLR4 parser errors in code when Intellij plugin constructs it correctly

Tags: java, parsing, intellij-idea, antlr4

I am attempting to construct a compiler for the golfing language [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) and am using ANTLR for parsing. I have managed to write down almost the entire language, and it works perfectly in the Intellij plugin for ANTLR, but when I try running the code using the input `⟨1|2⟩⟨1|2⟩`, it says `line 1:10 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting <a bunch of random characters>`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55661767), but my lexer and parser rules are in the same file, and I have already confirmed that the tokens are correct.

My grammar:

```
grammar Vyxal;

@header {
package io.github.seggan.jyxal.antlr;
}

file
    : program EOF
    ;

program
    : (literal | structure | element)+
    ;

element
    : PREFIX? element_type
    ;

element_type
    : ALPHA | '<' | ':' | '\u00d7' | '\u1e40' | '\u1e6b' | '\u2087' | '\u00be' | '\u2084' | '\u21b5'
    | '\u00b9' | '\u03a0' | '\u00e6' | '\u1e61' | '\u2211' | '\u1e8e'    | '\u221a' | '\u1e0b' | '\u00a7'
    | '\u00b2' | '\u2026' | '\u1e45' | '\u017b' | '\u01cd' | '-' | '\u2235' | '\u2194' | '\u2260' | '\u027e'
    | '\u00a4' | '\u20b4' | '\u01cf'    | '\u21e7' | '\u0121' | '\u1e8f' | '\u207c' | '\u204b' | '\u2229'
    | '\u2248' | '\u2237' | '\u2088' | '\u00f7' | '\u0227' | '\u0280' | '\u2080' | '\u1e02' | '\u228d'
    | '\u2234'    | '\u2228' | '\u022f' | '\u2070' | '\u1e8a' | '\u21e9' | '\u1e87' | '\u2039' | '\u1e2d'
    | '\u2020' | '\u201f' | '\u2308' | '\u2081' | '!' | '\u20ac' | '\u0188' | '\u01d2'    | '\u027d' | '\u0281'
    | ',' | '\u022e' | '\u22ce' | '\u03c4' | '\u01ce' | '\u1e59' | '%' | '\u1e86' | '\u2227' | '\u21b2'
    | '\u01d0' | '\u00a2' | '\u201e' | '\u0116'    | '\u2082' | '\u1e1e' | '\ua60d' | '}' | '*' | '\u1e8b'
    | '?' | '\u2085' | '\u0140' | '\u00df' | '\u27c7' | '\u2105' | '\u00a5'| '\u2086' | '\u0120' | '\u1e57'
    | '\u221e' | '\u1e56' | '\ua71d' | '\u01d3' | '\u203a' | '\u03b5' | '\u25a1' | '\u1e6a' | '\u00a6'
    | '\u0117' | '$' | '\u1e58' | '\u0130' | '=' | '\u2193' | '\u010b'    | '\u2083' | '\u1e22' | '_' | '\u27d1'
    | '\u010a' | '\u013f' | '\u00ac' | '\u00b6' | '\u00f0' | '\u1e1f' | '\u00a1' | '\u00af' | '\u2265'
    | '\u01d4' | '\u017c' | '\u2191'    | '\u1e0a' | '\u00bc' | '\u22cf' | '\u01d1' | '>' | '\u1e41' | '\u00a3'
    | '\u215b' | '\u1e23' | '+' | '\u00b1' | '/' | '\u21b3' | '\u222a' | '\u2207' | '\u2264'    | '\u1e03'
    | '\u2310' | '^' | '\u1e60' | '\u0226' | '\u03b2' | '\u2022' | '\u00bd' | '\u1e44'
    ;

// structures
structure
    : if_statement
    | for_loop
    | while_loop
    | lambda
    | function
    | variable_assn
    ;

if_statement
    : '[' program ('|' program)? ']'?
    ;

for_loop
    : '(' (variable '|')? program ')'?
    ;

while_loop
    : '{' (program '|')? program '}'?
    ;

lambda
    : LAMBDA_TYPE (integer '|')? program ';'?
    ;

function
    : '@' variable ((':' parameter (':' parameter)*)? '|' program)? ';'?
    ;

variable_assn
    : ASSN_SIGN variable
    ;

variable
    : (ALPHA | DIGIT)+
    ;

parameter
    : '*' | variable | integer
    ;


// types
literal
    : number
    | string
    | list
    ;

string
    : normal_string
    | compressed_string
    | single_char_string
    | double_char_string
    ;

number
    : integer
    | complex
    | compressed_number
    ;

integer
    : DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?
    ;

complex
    : integer '°' integer
    ;

list
    : '\u27e8' program ('|' program)* '\u27e9'?
    ;

any_text
    : .+?
    ;

compressed_string
    : '\u00ab' any_text '\u00ab'?
    ;

normal_string
    : '`' any_text '`'?
    ;

single_char_string
    : '\\' .
    ;

double_char_string
    : '‛' . .
    ;

compressed_number
    : '\u00bb' any_text '\u00bb'?
    ;

DIGIT
    : [0-9]
    ;


// code
PREFIX
    : [¨Þkø∆]
    ;

ALPHA
    : [a-zA-Z]
    ;

ASSN_SIGN
    : '→' | '←'
    ;

// strucutres
LAMBDA_TYPE
    : [λƛ'µ]
    ;

WHT
    : [ \t\n\r] -> skip
    ;
```

The code I use is simple:

```
String s = Files.readString(Path.of(args[0]));
VyxalLexer lexer = new VyxalLexer(CharStreams.fromString(s));
VyxalParser parser = new VyxalParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
```

The Intellij plugin constructs it properly:
[image: ANTLR Intellij plugin output]

And the tokens are of the correct values:

```
[@-1,0:0='⟨',<163>,1:0]
[@-1,1:1='1',<170>,1:1]
[@-1,2:2='|',<154>,1:2]
[@-1,3:3='2',<170>,1:3]
[@-1,4:4='⟩',<164>,1:4]
[@-1,5:5='⟨',<163>,1:5]
[@-1,6:6='1',<170>,1:6]
[@-1,7:7='|',<154>,1:7]
[@-1,8:8='2',<170>,1:8]
[@-1,9:9='⟩',<164>,1:9]
```

Comment: The question marks were simply the way my console renders `⟨` and `⟩`

Comment: Note that they are not parentheses, but mathematical brackets. `\u27e8` and `\u27e9` respectively :)

Comment: Doesn't matter if I use `(...)` or `⟨...⟩`: works on my machine

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ displays this:

[image]

And when I run:

```java
VyxalLexer lexer = new VyxalLexer(CharStreams.fromString("⟨1|2⟩⟨1|2⟩"));
VyxalParser parser = new VyxalParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
System.out.println(parser.file().toStringTree(parser));
```

the following is printed:

```
(file (program (literal (list ⟨ (program (literal (number (integer 1)))) | (program (literal (number (integer 2)))) ⟩)) (literal (list ⟨ (program (literal (number (integer 1)))) | (program (literal (number (integer 2)))) ⟩))) <EOF>)
```

Which is in sync with what IntelliJ displays.

I'm guessing you haven't recently generated new parser classes. Causing your own Java code to use older parser classes than the IntelliJ plugin is using.

Comment: The output is wrong. It is supposed to be a list, not a for loop. I have regenerated my classes, and run the exact code you provided. My output was `(file (program (element � element_type) (element � element_type) (literal (number (integer 1)))) | 2 � � � 1 | 2 �)`, as well as a bunch of errors.

Comment: My output does represent a `list`. I cannot see what the image you posted is supposed to represent, it is too small. But the `toStringTree` is the same as the image from my IntelliJ, which is the exact same grammar you posted in your question. You might still be using old (cached) parser classes: try doing a hard clean be deleting all class files.

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting to an earlier edit.

Comment: I never changed `(file (program (literal (list ...`: it always contained a `list`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Still, if you're getting errors, I really think you're working with stale parser class-files. I'd try deleting the *.class files manually.

Comment: Your `toStringTree` doesn't show a `list` at all.

Comment: I never said it did. Anyway, I must have looked something over, thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, but you got it working, without errors? You're welcome, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241878/discussion-between-seggan-and-bart-kiers).